# ISAPI Rewrite 301 Redirect Mapfile Not Working

Tags: url-rewriting, http-status-code-301, isapi

I have 10K of redirects for a large new site redesign and I cannot paste them in the ISAPI editor - It just dies when I click 'Apply' and I get a non responsive program and windows closes it. They are usual 301 old url to new (Like this)

```
RewriteRule ^models/308.htm$ /peugeot-308/ [R=301,L] 
RewriteRule ^models/4007.htm$ /peugeot-4007/ [R=301,L]
```

I am trying this as a mapfile option but its not picking up any of the 301 redirects in the txt file? This is what I have

```
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteBase /  
RewriteMap mapfilemodels txt:D:\websites\Production\sitename\htdocs\modelredirects.txt 
RewriteRule ^/(.*) ${mapfilemodels:$1} [R=301,L]
```

And in my text file I have the following old urls and new urls?

```
m/alfa-romeo-page.htm /alfa-romeo/ 
m/ford-page.htm /ford/ 
models/308.htm /peugeot-308/ 
models/301.htm /peugeot-301/
```

Any idea why this isn't working? Or any other idea how I can get these in place

Answer (score 0):

Few ideas to try:

1. Use `/` instead of `\` when declaring absolute path to rewrite map file. TBH this should work either way .. but, at least, this is how it is done in ISAPI_Rewrite examples.

2. I think this pattern is a bit wrong `^/(.*)` -- I do not think you need leading slash here.

Considering all aforementioned, try this:

```
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteBase /  
RewriteMap mapfilemodels txt:D:/websites/Production/sitename/htdocs/modelredirects.txt 
RewriteRule ^(.*) ${mapfilemodels:$1} [R=301,L]
```